# AAPT: Error: Resource attr/(various) not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Having all kinds of problems tonight. Downloaded updated Android Studio and Gradle and coded a little and then started getting these errors. Have tried uninstalling android studio, changing the version of Gradle in my build file to an earlier version, using an older version of android studio, deleting the Gradle cache, and maybe one or three other things. Older versions of Android Studio now say my project must be used with Android 3.6.

These things the build output is complaining about all seem to exist in the file it's talking about at the exact line. Tried commenting them out... that didn't work either.

Little out of my league here. Any of you gray hairs see something I'm missing?

Any help much appreciated.

===========================================================================

> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:268:5-4347:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:268:5-4347:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/flow_verticalSeparator) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:269:5-3548:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:269:5-3548:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/flow_verticalSeparator) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:271:5-4382:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:271:5-4382:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/flow_verticalSeparator) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:271:5-4382:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionProgress) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:274:5-588:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionProgress) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:275:5-652:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionProgress) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:284:5-653:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionProgress) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:284:5-653:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/waveDecay (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/waveDecay) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:288:5-232:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionPathRotate (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionPathRotate) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:290:5-295:36:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionProgress) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:318:5-232:
> AAPT: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka
> com.myproject.myproject:attr/motionProgress) not found.
> C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d083c96bf16f0afa497f0903aac86f7e\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:322:5-335:98:
> AAPT: error: reso

Comment: clean project and then rebuild project

Comment: i think problem is with the layout

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Update: 
Added  `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'` to my app's `build.gradle` file and it worked.

Pretty simple question but going to leave this up there. Might save someone a few hours of ignorance.

Comment: Or if you have the line already, select it, press ALT-ENTER and select "Change to 2.0.0-rc1" and then ALT-ENTER again and select "Sync"

Answer (score 0):

My case was really different. I had set **android:text=" ??? "** in my layout file, when I changed it to **android:text=" ? "** it worked. I have no idea why this works, maybe it helps someone. It took me hours to find the issue.